# how to add components into reusuable component? react

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm not sure my title make sense :/ sorry for my poor description.

anyway what I was trying was.. making a reusuable component.
and the props of the reusuable component is another component.

here's what I did:

```js
const Accordion = ({ title, content }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Title>{title}</Title>
      <Content>{content}</Content>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const title = () => <div>title</div>;
  const content = () => {
  return (<div><h2>...text...</h2><div>...text..</div></div>)
  }

  return <Accordion title={title} content={content} />;
};
```

it seems nice to me, but it does not work 
the title and the content(...text...) was not showing at all.

it works in this way though, this is not what I want

```js
  <Accordion title='title text' content='content context' />;
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Simply provide jsx to title and content variables, like so: `const title = <div>title</div>` and `const content = <div><h2>...text...</h2><div>...text..</div></div>`

Comment: thanks a lot!! it was super simple lol thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

**You need to render it like `<element />`**

```
const Accordion = ({ title, content }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Title><title /></Title>
      <Content><content /></Content>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```